# Can image load event be synchronous, or will it always be asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, dom

Let's say I have the following code:

```
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener("load", function() {
    alert("Loaded!");
});
img.src = external_string; // Can "load" fire here?
```

The question is - if the image in `external_string` is already in browser cache, or maybe is base64 encoded, or whatever - can it so happen that the `load` event is called immediately at the same line as `src` is being assigned?

Note: I actually want it to be asynchronous because I want to set up a few more things before the `load` event gets fired. But if there is a chance that it might get fired synchronously then I need to put in extra work to postpone that.

I could not find this subtlety explained in any document, but practical tests always call the event asynchronously.

Comment: Check out the [decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method. You can use that to tell when the image is ready for viewing

Comment: @Phil - That's just the same thing but with a different syntax. Even if I used it the question would remain - is it possible that the Promise returned from `decode()` is already resolved?

Comment: Does it matter if it is? It will always return a promise

Comment: `the load event is called immediately at the same line as src is being assigned?` never, events are always *asynchronous* in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) method to wait for images to be ready. Even if the image loads immediately, queuing the promise [micro-task](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue) will always ensure code runs after the promise resolves

> Promise handlers `.then`/`.catch`/`.finally` are **always asynchronous**.
>
> Even when a Promise is immediately resolved, the code on the lines *below* `.then`/`.catch`/`.finally` will still execute before these handlers.

```js
// Base64 data URI requires no loading time
const red_dot = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = red_dot;
img.decode().then(() => {
  console.log("img ready, this will log second");
  document.body.append(img);
});
console.log("img loading, this will log first");
```

Keep in mind that you cannot call `decode()` before setting `src`.

---

The *load* event will also always trigger and a listener can be added at any time however since it relies on the [event loop](https://javascript.info/event-loop), control over the order of operations is non-deterministic. That being said, any procedural code you add after setting the `src` will always execute before the event handler fires.

```js
// Base64 data URI requires no loading time
const red_dot = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

const img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log("img ready, this will log second");
  document.body.append(img);
});
img.src = red_dot;
console.log("img loading, this will log first");
```